# Raise position of text relative to line

Tags: height, raise

It's a relatively minor thing, but in the table below I'd like to raise up the Hebrew relative to the Latin characters.  They feel like they're sitting slightly too low on each line.  Can anyone provide any suggestions please?

Thanks in advance,

James.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{cjhebrew}
\usepackage{longtable}

\usepackage{array} % for ExtraRowHeight
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}}

\begin{document}

\Large
\fontfamily{bch}
\selectfont

\linespread{1.06}
\begin{longtable}{Lp{1cm}Rp{4.6cm}Lp{9.2cm}}

1.1 & \cjRL{b*i+s:nat +sAlwo+s l:mal:kw*t y:hwoyAqiyM mElEK:--y:hw*dAh b*A' n:bw*kad:nE'.s*ar mElEK:--b*AbEl y:rw*+sAlaiM way*A.sar `AlEyhA;} & In the 3\textsuperscript{rd} year of the reign of Jehoiakim (the King of Judah), Nebuchadnezzar (the King of Babylon) came {[}to{]} Jerusalem and laid siege to it, \\
1.2 & \cjRL{way*it*eN 'a:donAy b*:yAdwo 'Et--y:hwoyAqiyM mElEK:--y:hw*dAh w*miq:.sAt k*:ley beyt--hA'E:lohiyM way:biy'eM 'ErE.S--+sin:`Ar b*eyt 'E:lohAyw w:'Et--hak*eliyM hebiy' b*eyt 'wo.sar 'E:lohAyw;} & and the Lord gave Jehoiakim (the King of Judah) into his hand, together with odds-and-ends from the vessels\textmd{\footnote{lit., `from the end of the vessels'; colloq., `part of the vessels'}} of the House of God.\space\space {[}Nebuchadnezzar{]} brought them {[}both to{]} the Land of Shinar, {[}to{]} the house of \textit{his} god, where he brought the vessels into his god's treasure-house. \\

\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Isn't it just an optical illusion? Caused by the vowel (?) accents in the hebrew.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a general alteration of the font, but only to this particular `longtable` case.  I introduce `\shcjRL` that shifts up 1pt in vertical space before invoking `\cjRL`.  It assumes an invocation at the beginning of a paragraph, which applies in this case.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{cjhebrew}
\usepackage{longtable}
\def\shcjRL#1{\vspace{\dimexpr-\normalbaselineskip-1pt}\par\cjRL{#1}}

\usepackage{array} % for ExtraRowHeight
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}}

\begin{document}

\Large
\fontfamily{bch}
\selectfont

\linespread{1.06}
\begin{longtable}{Lp{1cm}Rp{4.6cm}Lp{9.2cm}}

1.1 & \shcjRL{b*i+s:nat +sAlwo+s l:mal:kw*t y:hwoyAqiyM mElEK:--y:hw*dAh b*A' n:bw*kad:nE'.s*ar mElEK:--b*AbEl y:rw*+sAlaiM way*A.sar `AlEyhA;} & In the 3\textsuperscript{rd} year of the reign of Jehoiakim (the King of Judah), Nebuchadnezzar (the King of Babylon) came {[}to{]} Jerusalem and laid siege to it, \\
1.2 & \shcjRL{way*it*eN 'a:donAy b*:yAdwo 'Et--y:hwoyAqiyM mElEK:--y:hw*dAh w*miq:.sAt k*:ley beyt--hA'E:lohiyM way:biy'eM 'ErE.S--+sin:`Ar b*eyt 'E:lohAyw w:'Et--hak*eliyM hebiy' b*eyt 'wo.sar 'E:lohAyw;} & and the Lord gave Jehoiakim (the King of Judah) into his hand, together with odds-and-ends from the vessels\textmd{\footnote{lit., `from the end of the vessels'; colloq., `part of the vessels'}} of the House of God.\space\space {[}Nebuchadnezzar{]} brought them {[}both to{]} the Land of Shinar, {[}to{]} the house of \textit{his} god, where he brought the vessels into his god's treasure-house. \\

\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect!  Out of interest, how come it only works in the longtable case?

Comment: @JamesBejon Well, It only works if invoked at the beginning of a paragraph, really (and doesn't account for non-zero values of `\parskip`),.  So it could work in a `tabular` "p" column as long as you invoked it the same way.  However, for a reason I can't explain, if I change `longtable` to `tabular`, the definition's multiplier on `\normalbaselineskip` needs adjustment: `\def\shcjRL#1{\vspace{\dimexpr-.7\normalbaselineskip-1pt}\par\cjRL{#1}}`